# Testdata rollback - Selenium test on UI

Tags: database, selenium, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am currently making automated tests in Selenium. All of these tests are exported in java format and imported into IntelliJ. These tests are runned on the UI (web-interface) and it makes entries in the database. This is only test data, so after each test, I want to delete the entries made in the database (not manually...). My tests can only run once now because the data already exists and it does not allow duplicated data.
All of the tests go through the UI. DBunit has already been tested in the company and its decided not to use it. Any other options?

Comment: Write more intelligent tests.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Using JDBC with Java to Create Methods that manipulate or define data in before and after method.